# How to get index ID of a specific column from CSV file

Tags: c#

I am doing this:

```
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.FILE], Constants.ENCODING))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
    string[] colFields = parser.ReadFields();

    foreach (string column in colFields)
    {
        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
        if (column == "Column001")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is
when column name equals variable
I want to add it to datatable column and get it's index ID(I want to know what colFields[?] have the name of variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the index of the column, you should use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < colFields.Length; ++i)
{
    string column = colFields[i];
    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
    if (column == "Column001")
    {
    }
}
```

As you can see, you now have the index in `i`.